# How do I align the navbar logo to the far left of the screen with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

I would like to align the logo in the navbar to the far left of the screen. Right now it's placed a little bit to the center. I've tried multiple bootstrap classes together with the "navbar-brand" class, but I can't seem to get it to work. I would appreciate help!

The line I want help with is:
`<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" width="90" height="80" alt=""></a>`

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0">
    <div class="container">

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" width="90" height="80" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Do you want it to align left completely, as it is already in left?

Comment: @Manas Yes, should have clarified that!

Comment: No problem just remove the `div` with the class of `container`. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you can see logo is on the left....

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0">
  

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="90" height="80" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
  
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified that I want it to be at the far left of the screen!

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the `div` with the class of `container` as it is adding a `margin` on the `left` and `right`**

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top py-lg-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">logo</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="products.html">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

---

> Check code at Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/BaoVvMe